What causes 'RenderFlex overflowed' errors in Flutter, and how can I fix them?
The 'RenderFlex overflowed' error occurs due to widgets exceeding available space in a layout. please suggest me with proper solutions.
I tried using a Row widget to align multiple buttons horizontally, expecting them to fit within the screen. However, I didn’t account for the limited width on smaller screens. As a result, a 'RenderFlex overflowed' error appeared, with a yellow and black striped bar indicating the overflow. Instead of the buttons being displayed properly, they were cut off and stretched beyond the screen boundaries.

Hello, please provide enough code so we can better understand or reproduce the problem
